# output only the non empty content of some columns of data in a title in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

i have a title of dynamically outputed plots which change every time we filter the data using predefined combinations of settings .The title is supposed to show some string pasted to the contents of the columns of data coming from loading that excel file of settings.My problem is that some columns are left empty intentionnaly.The title is nice but showing also NA and i want to get rid of that .Code below.

```
filters<-readxl("settings1.xlsx") {settings1 is defined as follows:manufacturer=audi,model="",displ=1.8,year=1999)
data<-mpg  
                                          
ggplot(filtrated data, aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
  geom_point(size = 7, colour = "#EF783D", shape = 17) +
  geom_line(color = "#EF783D") +
        ggtitle(paste0("Insights :","  ",paste0(filters$manufacturer,filters$model,filters$displ,filters$year,collapse = ",")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far from what I have understood your problem since the `filters` dataframe has a column with missing value or empty value, suppose `model` has `NA` value, and `NA` appears in the plot title. So to remove it, I have tried to solve it by changing the `filters` data frame a bit.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(mpg)

filters <- data.frame(manufacturer = "audi", model=NA, displ=1.8, year=1999)

filters <- filters %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), as.character)
  ) %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(list(manufacturer = "", model = "", displ = "", year = ""))


ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = cty)) +
  geom_point(size = 7, colour = "#EF783D", shape = 17) +
  geom_line(color = "#EF783D") +
  ggtitle(
    paste("Insights :", paste(unlist((filters)), collapse = " "))
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: it does not help.in fact NA should be not outputed at all either zero nor somethng else .Additonally i have a bunch of excel files means many filters so they do have the same name of colomns but some columns which are emtpy in some files are not in others

Comment: Yes, In the above plot, Look there's no `NA` in plot-title when in `filters` model has `NA`

Comment: yes but there s zero and i want to show nothing ths means to show only non empty columns

Comment: @samir, have a look, does it now solve your problem? model is `NA` so it is not in the plot title.

Comment: ok this is nice!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is non-reproducible, but this should do:

```
filters<-readxl("settings1.xlsx") {settings1 is defined as follows:manufacturer=audi,model="",displ=1.8,year=1999)
data<-mpg  
                                          
ggplot(filtrated data, aes(x = displ, y = cty)) + 
  geom_point(size = 7, colour = "#EF783D", shape = 17) +
  geom_line(color = "#EF783D") +
        ggtitle(paste("Insights : ", na.omit(filters$manufacturer), na.omit(filters$model), na.omit(filters$displ), na.omit(filters$year), sep = ", ")))
```

Comment: i am grateful! you cannot now how much you helped me